# Why st_distance('polygon from north pole', 'point in italy') gives me '0' as a result?

Tags: sql, postgresql, gis, postgis

I am developing an application using PostgreSQL as database; my goal is to archive polygon datas in geography format so i can visualize them easily using pgAdmin OpenStreetMap integration when i make some query. My problem is that when i try to show the distance in meters between a polygon settled approximately in the north pole and a point settled in Italy, the distance gives me a result of '0' and I know that a distance is zero when the polygon itself contains the point... but this is not our case.
The code below is the query I used for this example:

```
SELECT 
  ST_Distance('POLYGON((88.20524 80.31286,89.30506 88.84312,83.62463 89.51824,88.20524 80.31286))'::geography, 
  ST_MakePoint(14.295750, 40.898207)::geography)
```

Can you help me to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: My db gives this distance: 5250148.71116661 - would that be what you expect?

Comment: Did you just copy and paste my code? Because, in my case like I said before, I obtain zero as distance

Comment: That's odd. Could you also add the PostgreSQL and PostGIS version you're using? I believe you're using an outdated version ..

Comment: and yes, I just executed your query without and modification :)

Comment: PostgreSQL version: 12.1
PostGIS: 3.0 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1

Comment: I'm using PostGIS 2.4 and it seems fine. I'll try to check with a newer version to see if I can reproduce the bug - I've seen it happening at 2.4.4 :-P

Comment: I get zero too for the record.  Postgres.11.1, postgis 2.5 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1

Comment: I can confirm the zero result with PostGIS 3.0 on PostgreSQL 12.1.

Comment: I just installed your environment and I could reproduce your error. As of now I cannot say it is a bug introduced at 2.5.. it will require some research: https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/4223

Comment: So it's just a bug of the newer version we're using? I'm currently testing other query involved in my project and many of them that are involved in calculations with north/south pole points (so the "limits" point of earth) give me strange errors as results.

Comment: @GDC Strangely enough this bug has been reported as fixed. I'm unable to find any workaround :-( it works fine using `geometry` columns instead of `geography`, but it means you'd have the distance in degrees

Comment: I know it works with geometry column but I need distance in meters because i'm developing an application based on a search engine of points (gym centers) and polygon (center operators with their polygon influence on the map) so when a client makes a request the DB must send distance and other informations in a human readable mode... now I'm switching to PostgreSQL 10 with PostGIS 2.4.0 as you suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe PostGIS 3.0 is having some trouble with the amount of decimals you have in your coordinates.

Reduce the decimal precision by 1 digit, e.g. `ST_MakePoint(14.29575, 40.89820)`, and it should work. It's not a solution I am very proud of, but assuming it is a bug in ST_Distance I believe it's an acceptable workaround.

```
SELECT 
  ST_Distance('POLYGON((88.20524 80.31286,89.30506 88.84312,83.62463 89.51824,88.20524 80.31286))'::geography, 
  ST_MakePoint(14.29575, 40.89820)::geography);

   st_distance    
------------------
 5250149.46929165
(1 Zeile)
```

**Testing envorinment**

```
SELECT version();
                                                                   version                                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 12.1 (Ubuntu 12.1-1.pgdg16.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit
(1 Zeile)

SELECT postgis_full_version();
                                                                                        postgis_full_version                                                                                         
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 POSTGIS="3.0.0 r17983" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="120" GEOS="3.7.1-CAPI-1.11.1 27a5e771" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.2, 08 September 2015" LIBXML="2.9.3" LIBJSON="0.11.99" LIBPROTOBUF="1.2.1" WAGYU="0.4.3 (Internal)"
(1 Zeile)
```

I'm trying to make sense out of this result set, but it seems that `ST_Distance` cannot cope with a certain combination of decimal points between points and polygons. With the given polygon it won't work if the point has **more than 5 decimal digits**:

```
WITH j (p1,p2) AS (
  VALUES ('POLYGON((88.20524 80.31286,89.30506 88.84312,83.62463 89.51824,88.20524 80.31286))',
          'POINT(14.295750 40.898207)')
) 
SELECT 
  ST_Distance(ST_AsText(p1,5)::GEOGRAPHY,
              ST_AsText(p2,5)::GEOGRAPHY) AS five_digits,
  ST_Distance(ST_AsText(p1,6)::GEOGRAPHY,
              ST_AsText(p2,6)::GEOGRAPHY) AS six_digits
FROM j;

   five_digits    | six_digits 
------------------+------------
 5250148.38625588 |          0
(1 Zeile)
```

Further reading:

- [`ST_AsText()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsText.html) - max decimal digits

Comment: I'm doing some tests and this seems to be the best fix for that problem! Thanks everyone! :D

Comment: @GDC it is definitely not a solution I'm very proud of, but I hope it helps you until the bug is fixed:)